# IntelliJ downloads Gradle dependencies but cannot find them during compile

Tags: intellij-idea, compilation, gradle

IntelliJ downloaded the dependencies listed in my build.gradle file and they show up in the External Library, but IntelliJ fails to find them during compile.  It just throws a bunch of "package x does not exist" and "cannot resolve symbol".  Under the Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies they all show up and are listed as compile.

If I try to build it with Gradle it's successful, so it's just IntelliJ.  Any ideas?

If it's important, I'm using this on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.  IntelliJ was treating Main and Test as modules with no dependency related to the project itself and all of the library dependencies were stored at the project level.

I killed off Main and Test as modules and it sorted itself out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! Run time scope sucks