# Can't import dependencies that have been downloaded to .m2

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm importing dependencies via Maven:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1203-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
```

I checked `C://Users/user/.m2/repository` and I can see those dependencies in `.jar` files in respective folders/packages. However when I try to import those in code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```

I get `Cannot resolve symbol` error:

[image]

I tried;

```
mvn clean
mvn install
mvn clean install
```

I get compile error on `mvn install`. I tried removing all source code fromt he project and then `mvn install`, it resulted in `Build Success`, however once the source code is added, I can't use the dependency classes.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27804731/4759176) helped me. Turned out the dependencies Maven downloaded were assigned a Run time scope (whose idea was to invent this useless error-prone scope??). I set the scope to compile (File - Project structure - Modules - Dependencies - Scope) and it works fine.

Comment: `runtime` is a very useful scope, to avoid the accidental use of an implementation where only the API should be used.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using the "compile" scope to solved the problem. It shows a very wild behavior and undebuggable.

Comment: @cyang nice to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong you should check your project from first:

1. maven Repositories in your IDE Updated True?
2. run "mvn Clean" in IDE Console
3. Reimport  All maven Project
4. go to pom.xml and check your dependencies.

Good luck.